# Why is Atom not using the virtualenv I've activated in the Atom terminal?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, virtualenv, atom-editor

I am currently working on a web application and I've been using a conda-managed virtualenv containing Django 1.10 and Python 3.5 packages. I've been able to run a server and see the progress of the web app via the virtualenv so far, but now I'm getting errors that suggest Atom is no longer utilizing the virtualenv I have activated. First it was that django was not installed--I typed the command "conda list" to make sure the package was still there and it was, but I re-installed it. Then the server error told me python2 was being used rather than python3 despite the fact that the latter was installed in my virtualenv (this discrepancy caused an error related to changes between python2 and python3). The only thing I've done between the last time the server worked and now: I quit atom, took a break, came back, and reactivated my virtualenv (but now I cannot get the webpage to load). I think some configurations got messed up and I don't know how to fix it. Perhaps relatedly, I'm also getting binary files in Atom for all my .py files (admin, view, models, etc.) and I don't know why--I've completed a handful of small projects and this has never happened. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This shows that my env is activated and has django and python installed:

[image]

Update: I just tried to create a new env (called new) in Anaconda and install packages needed by the project and for some reason Atom is still using a package base other than the environment I have active (clearly django is not installed in the (new) virtual env):

[image]

Another Update: I just ran everything in my Mac's default terminal application and the page loads fine. Something fishy is going on with Atom's terminal and I don't know what. Would still like an answer to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

activate the virtual environment with

> activate (virtual environment name)

and then in anaconda prompt type:

> atom --new-instance

This will open atom with virtual environment, You might need to Have Hydrogen and Scripts package installed.